# Preload content before showing jQuery ajax load() content

Tags: jquery

I want to fill a div with some images got through jQuery ajax load() function (dynamically, from a PHP script), but I want to show a preload imagem until all photos are loaded. Can anyone help me on this point?

Here's the code as it is right now (it shows the images, but shows them loading):

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.lista_fotos').hide();
                $('.evento').click(function(){
                    if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
                        $('.evento').removeClass('evento_activo').next().slideUp();
                        $(this).toggleClass('evento_activo').next().slideDown();
                        var evento = $(this).text();
                        var pasta = $(this).attr("rel");
                        var ano = $(this).attr("name");
                        $(this).next().load('fotos_evento.php', { evento: evento, ano: ano, pasta: pasta });
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).removeClass('evento_activo').next().slideUp();
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ricardo ,

You can do the following thing , make a image which looks like a busy indicator which is like loading.gif or so ...first load the div background image as loading image

I am giving an example

// make your background image as loading here

you have a call back which says that loading is complicated , in the call back function remove the loading image and load your images.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
 // load completed , hide your busy indicator and use your images from php
});
```

Comment: But the images are printed in the PHP script.

Comment: What the callback means by completed load in this case? Printing "<img src=......" or image loading?

Answer (score 0):

To wait for images to [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) you can use .load to bind a handler to the image.  (Not to be confused with the .load you are already using to make an ajax call).  Something like this:

$('#myImage').load(function() {
  // this fires when the image is finished loading.
});

Comment: <?php
 $pasta = $_POST['pasta'];
 $ano = $_POST['ano']; 
 $evento = utf8_decode($_POST['evento']);
 $fotos = scandir($pasta.$ano."/".$evento."/");
 $evento = rawurlencode($evento);
 array_shift($fotos);
 array_shift($fotos);
 foreach($fotos as $foto) {
  $foto = rawurlencode($foto);
  echo "<a rel='lightbox' class='link_foto' href='".$pasta.$ano."/".$evento."/".$foto."'><img class='foto' src='".$pasta.$ano."/".$evento."/".$foto."'></a>";
 }

Comment: I've tried something like this in the PHP script, but it didn't work:
<div id="preloader" class="centrar"><img src="imagens/loading.gif"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.link_foto').hide();

$('.link_foto').load(function() {
 $('#preloader').hide();
 $('.link_foto').show();
});
</script>

Comment: <?php
 $pasta = $_POST['pasta'];
 $ano = $_POST['ano']; 
 $evento = utf8_decode($_POST['evento']);
 $fotos = scandir($pasta.$ano."/".$evento."/");
 $evento = rawurlencode($evento);
 array_shift($fotos);
 array_shift($fotos);
 foreach($fotos as $foto) {
  $foto = rawurlencode($foto);
  echo "<a rel='lightbox' class='link_foto' href='".$pasta.$ano."/".$evento."/".$foto."'><img class='foto' src='".$pasta.$ano."/".$evento."/".$foto."'></a>";
 }

?>

Comment: I don't think you can attach load to the container.  I think you have to attach it right to the image itself.  I haven't really used it before, so I'm not entirely sure.